# Can a FileSystemEnumerableIterator directly use StrCmpLogicalW to do a logical sort?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Is there a way to directly use the `StrCmpLogicalW` Win32 function when retrieving a list of files from a folder? I need to do a logical sort where the leading numerical digits are treated as numbers.

The built in function `OrderBy<>` and `OrderByDescending<>` do a character based sort.

In the code below I copy the collection to a List and then do the sort. It works, but it seems like an extra step.//

```
/// <summary>
/// Descending logical sort for lists with numeric data
/// </summary>
public class StrCmpLogicalDescendingComparer : Comparer<string>
{
  [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string x, string y);

  public override int Compare(string x, string y)
  {
    // Provide elements in reverse order to sort descending
    return StrCmpLogicalW(y, x);
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Examine folder and return the next file number in sequence
/// </summary>
/// <param name="folder"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private int FindNextFileNumber(string folder)
{
  int result = -1;
  // Return an array of file names from the folder

  // Original attempt, does a character sort
  //var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder)
  //              .OrderByDescending(filename => filename);

  var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder);
  if (files.Count() > 0) {
    // Convert the collection to a list that can use the logical sorter
    List<string> sortableList = files.ToList();//= new List<string>();
    sortableList.Sort(new StrCmpLogicalDescendingComparer());
    foreach (string file in sortableList) {
      // Files with alpha will not qualify as a number, loop will
      // keep trying until it finds the highest number
      if (Int32.TryParse(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), out result)) {
        result++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  // Check to see if there were any numeric files found
  if (result == -1) {
    result = 0;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Both `Enumerable.OrderBy` and `.OrderByDescending` have overloads that take an `IComparer`, so you can use `OrderByDescending` and not have to futz the comparison in the comparer itself.

Comment: OrderByDescending does not do a logical sort, unless there is an option I missed.

Comment: Your question concerned removing the copy and `.Sort`. `files.OrderByDescending(f => f, new StrCmpLogicalComparer())` (assuming you write a `StrCmpLogicalComparer` that does not invert its comparison). Be aware that in order to sort the collection, there's still going to be temporary memory allocated in the background, so you're probably not going to gain much in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are ordering a potentially large list of files when you are only interested in maybe just a few, that seems wasteful; imagine thousands of alphanumeric names and only a handful of numeric ones... ouch. Why not filter out *first* the files that are not numbers and *then* order the rest?

An important side benefit of this approach is that, once you *know* you only have numerical file names, its trivial to order them correctly without recurring to native functions:

```
static int FindNextFileNumber(string folder)
{
    var i = 0;

    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder)
                    .Where(f => int.TryParse(f, out i))
                    .Select(f => i)
                    .OrderByDescending(n => n)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: This is application has a very narrow scope and will normally only have numeric files in the target folders. While some folders may grow to as many as 5000 files, the majority will be less than 500. I only need to do the check once per session start and again only if somebody manually causes an issue like renaming a file or writing something there by mistake.

Comment: @RichShealer Comparing strings will always be more expensive than comparing integers, You are sorting strings, and then trying to parse them all. Filtering while parsing is basically free so not doing it is a missed chance, and then you can sort using int comparison which is cheaper.

Comment: @RichShealer But like you say, if your normal use case is 500 files once per session, that's not really an issue. Still you seem bent on using `StrCmpLogicalW` when its really not necessary, creating an avoidable dependency that today may not seem relevant but can be in the future no matter how far fetched it may seem to you now.

Comment: Okay it might be a wash in this case, but OrderByDescending will not do a true numeric sort, which was my initial question.  eg. 00200 and 010 would come through out of order. The application won't create them like this, and 99.99% of the time it will never be a problem, but it is possible for someone to rename a file incorrectly.